# ng2-tel-input: Country flag do not change automatically when manually change input

Tags: angular

I use [ng2-tel-input](https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input) with reactive form method (Angular).

**Issue:**
When i open flag dropdown and choose a value, it is working fine. 
Value is displayed into input correctly but country flag do not change and the default flag appear.

When I change value manually in input then flag changes automatically, otherwise default country flag displaying.

**Example:**
Value format: **+917878747474**
Selected country: **India**
Default country: **us**

**when i press on set value. phone no set on input but flag remain same**

**html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
        <small class="phone-text">{{ placeHolder }}</small>
        <md-input-container class="full-width pt-0">
            <input type="text"
                   mdInput
                   formControlName="phone"
                   ng2TelInput
                   [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: initialCountry}"
                   (hasError)="hasError($event)"
                   (ng2TelOutput)="hasOutPut($event)"
                   #phoneInput
                   maxlength="45"/>
        </md-input-container>
       <button type="button" (click)="setValue()">Set Value</button>
    </form>
```

**Component**

```
import {Attribute, Component, forwardRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-phone',
    templateUrl: './phone.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./phone.component.scss']
})
export class PhoneComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    placeHolder = 'Default Value';
    initialCountry = 'us';
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
        this._initForm();
    }

    setValue(): void {
        const phone = '+917878747416'
        this.form.setValue({phone: phone});
    }

    private _initForm(): void {
        this.form = this._fb.group({
            'phone': ['']
        });
    }

    hasError(event: any): void {
        if (!event && this.form.value.phone !== '') {
            this.form.get('phone').setErrors(['invalid_cell_phone', true]);
        }
    }

    hasOutPut(event: any): void {
        this.form.patchValue({phone: event});
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: i have created plunkr but i don't know how to add package in plunkr. i added but got 404. [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uEDUJa32MN5NSGCDzkAU?p=preview)

Comment: I created a small project, creating a reactive form as you say and using the code you provided and everything is working fine. Can you provide some more code or any other info, otherwise I don't think we can help you.

Comment: @Olezt i have updated Question and put my all code here. thanks for your time

Comment: Ok, now the problem is clear. You change your value programmatically from the component and the flag do not change. I was able to reproduce this but I can't find any workaround.

Comment: @Olezt thanks man. if any solution you will got post here.

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor I'm having the same problem did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="pd-mat-form-field-class" hideRequiredMarker>
 <label class="pd-mat-custom-label">{{"CELL_1" | translate }}</label>
 <mat-label></mat-label>
 <input ng2TelInput #intlInput 
   [ng2TelInputOptions]="cell1TelInput" 
   (hasError)="hasError1($event)" 
   (ng2TelOutput)="getNumberCellNo1($event)" 
   (intlTelInputObject)="cell1telInputObject($event)" 
   (countryChange)="onCell1CountryChange($event)" 
   type="text" 
   maxlength=14  class="pd-mat-form-input-margin"  
   matInput  name="cell_no1"
   formControlName = "cellnumber1" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Ts**

```
cell1TelInput = {
initialCountry: this.constant.defaultCountrycode, 
autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
nationalMode :true,
customPlaceholder: function(selectedCountryPlaceholder) {
  return 'Example : ' + selectedCountryPlaceholder;
}

  if (response.userCellNumbers[0] && response.userCellNumbers[0].cell_no) {
            this.cellnumber1 = response.userCellNumbers[0].cell_no;  
            this.cell_code1.setNumber(this.cellnumber1)     
          }

 getNumberCellNo1(e:any)
  {
    this.cell_code1.setNumber(e) 
    this.cellnumber1=e
  }

  public onCell1CountryChange(e: any) {
    this.cellnumber1DialCode =  e.dialCode;
    this.cell1TelInput.initialCountry = e.iso2
    this.cell_code1.setNumber("") 
  }

  public cell1telInputObject(obj) {
    this.cell_code1=obj
  }

  hasError1(event: any): void {
    if (!event && this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1 ) {
    this.uploadForm.get('cellnumber1').setErrors(['invalid_cell_phone', true]);
    }
    }

  if (this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1) {
      this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1 = this.cellnumber1
      this.cellNumbers.push( {"cell_no": this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1.replace(/\s/g, ""), "cell_type": 1});
    }`

    hasError() is used for validation
    The getNumber() will give you the country code and number as +919843133490.
    The setNumber() will set the country flag and place the number in input field.
    ng2TelInputOptions is used to initialize data

    Hope it helped. Any further queries can be asked.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy hack but worked:

So, if you just want to change the flag based on the input value, the component itself already detects keyup events and sets the flag based on the `dialCode` (e.g. if you start typing "+49", it would set the German flag).

Based on that, if you set the input field programmatically, it will not detect this keyup event, so I decided to hack it.

This answer helped me how to do that:
[Trigger keyup event in Angular 5 TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626631/trigger-keyup-event-in-angular-5-typescript)

Bind your input with ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('phoneInput')
phoneInput: ElementRef;
```

Trigger a fake keyup event:

```
setValue(): void {
  const phone = '+917878747416'
  this.form.setValue({phone: phone});
  this.phoneInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { bubbles: true })
  );
}
```

Worked out pretty smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text"
  ng2TelInput
  [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'in'}"
  (hasError)="hasError($event)"
  (ng2TelOutput)="getNumber($event)"
  (intlTelInputObject)="telInputObject($event)"
  (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" />
```

(The HTML above is from https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input)

```
 inputObj: any;

  telInputObject(obj, val) {
    this.inputObj = obj;
    if (this.contactNumber) {
      obj.setNumber(this.contactNumber);
    }
  }
```

on `ngOnInit()` check if `inputObj` is present if not set it

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(inputObj){
       inputObj.setNumber('+91987654321');
    }
}
```

setNumber will automaticaly detect flag

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
telInputObject(obj) {
    obj.setCountry("br");
    obj.setNumber("xxxxxx");
}
```